# How to Organize Javascript in Rails project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have ran into this couple times. So in rails 3, with the introduction of asset pipeline, we better separate javascript from the view. However, what if we want to forwards some instance variable from controller to the javascript? It seems like the only solution is to embed the javascript in the view. Is there any way to work around this? It feels like, the dynamic component is impossible to be separated from the view. This happens from time to time when I used the google visualization api. I constantly need to push large data to feed into the api.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy!

Say we have a controller with the following view for **index.html.erb**

```
#GET /index.html
def index
  @some_data = {:foo => [:bar0, :bar1]}
end
```

In our view (**index.html.erb**), we would embed the data in HTML first

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "index" %> 
<div id="home_page">

<!-- Pass members to javascript -->
<div id="self" data-some_data='<%= @some_data.to_json %>'></div>    

</div>
```

Finally, assuming we are using jQuery, we can simply access the data in **index.js**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  some_data = $("#self").data("some_data");
  alert(some_data.foo[0]);              //Says "bar0"
}
```

---

N.B. You would expect to have to use JSON.parse because of the magical ability to use the returned data like an object and not just a plain string, e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      //This will fail
      some_data = JSON.parse($("#self").data("some_data"));
      alert(some_data.foo[0]);              //Says "bar0"
    }
```

However, using JSON.parse **will not work**.  The returned information from JSON.parse is not **necessarily** a string, and in this case, it was a javascript object; [jQuery's data function](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) will try to implicitly convert strings to a reasonable javascript object.  In the case of a data attribute that contains a JSON string, the string inside the data attribute will be converted to a "javascript object".

If you don't like the magic behavior of `$.data`, you may use `JSON.parse($("#self").attr("data-some_data"))` in lieu of `$("#self").data("some_data")`

Answer (score 2):

You have three main options:

1. **Embedded JavaScript**

   Like you have suggested, you can embed a `<script>` tag in the page whose contents are dynamically determined.
2. **DOM**

   It is a common practice to have a hidden `<textarea>`, whose contents is some sort of data (generally JSON). On page load, you can use the DOM to access the element's value attribute.
3. **Separate HTTP Request**

   You can have the server serve up a JSON data, which you request via XMLHttpRequest, or other means.

Comment: I often use the DOM approach, I find it the tidiest from a code maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

One clean way to do it is the [Gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon). It's specifically for "getting your Rails variable to your js"

For a few other options see this [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) (or read the [ASCIIcasts transcript](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)).

Comment: I love the gem. Is there any disadvantage of using the gem in terms of speed?